# Validating and proving a property of Group Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I heard this statement in group isomorphism:

A group $G$ is isomorphic to $G'$ if $\exists\ \phi : G \to G'$ such that $\forall\ g \in G, |g|=|\phi(g)|$.

I don't have the proof of this property and I am not sure if it is correct. I think the property may be incorrect for groups of infinite order but I am not sure. For finite groups I think that saying that the order of $g$ is equal to the order of $\phi(g)$ is not enough. I think we also need to say that order of $G$ is equal to order of $G'$. Please help me understand this property and prove it if it is valid.

Comment: your ismorphism must also preserve relationships under your group operation.  $\forall g,h \in G, \phi (g+h) = \phi(g) * \phi(h)$ with "+" as the group operation in $G$ and "*" as the group operation in $G'.$

Comment: yes. It must be homomorphic in the first place to be isomorphic. But I was wondering if this property automatically takes care of that or not.

Comment: @ArpanBiswas If $\phi$ is not homomorphic the answer is not valid...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $I:G\rightarrow G\times G$ defined by $I(g)=(g,e)$. It is not an isomorphism, but $g$ and $I(g)$ have the same order.

But it is true if you assume that $\phi$ is also onto. In this case, let $x\in Ker(\phi)$, $\phi(x)=e$, implies that the order of $x$ is $1$, thus $x=e$. This implies that $\phi$ is injective, since it is supposed surjective, it is bijective and hence an isomorphism.

Comment: Not really,....

Comment: $G$ and $G\times G$ don't have the same cardinal if $G$ is finite, they can't be isomorphic since an isomorphism is a bijection.

Comment: Oh yes. Right !

Comment: @ArpanBiswas $I(g)=(g,g)$ is not surjective.

Comment: When the cardinality is the same (and finite), just use, that @TsemoAristide has shown $\phi$ is injective, hence bijective. So the statement is true for $ \#G=\#G'<\infty$.